# Interfaces using IDisposable

Tags: .net, design-patterns, idisposable

In regards to `IDisposable`

I'm creating interface that I would expect to use system resources most of the time, but not always.  Would it be prudent to anticipate the usage include `IDisposable` on my Interface?

For example I have an interface that provides a mean to synchronize to.

```
interface IDateTimeProvider : IDisposable
{
    int LeapSeconds {get;set;}
    DateTime LocalNow {get;}
    DateTime UtcNow {get;}
    DateTime GpsNow {get;}
}

class NtpTimeProvider : IDateTimeProvider
{
    // Assume client is setup and ready to use.
    // Obtains time via network resources
    NtpClient client;  

   NtpTimeProvider (int leapSeconds)
   { LeapSeconds = leapSeconds;}

    int LeapSeconds {get;set;}
    DateTime LocalNow {get{return client.Utc};}
    DateTime UtcNow {get{return client.Utc};}
    DateTime GpsNow {get{return client.Utc - TimeSpan.FronSeconds(LeapSeconds);}}
    void Dispose()
    {
        if(client != null) Client.Dispose();
    }
}


class SystemTimeProvider : IDateTimeProvider
{

   SystemTimeProvider (int leapSeconds)
   { LeapSeconds = leapSeconds;}

    int LeapSeconds {get;set;}
    DateTime LocalNow {get{return DateTime.Now};}
    DateTime UtcNow {get{return DateTime.UtcNow };}
    DateTime GpsNow {get{return DateTime.UtcNow - TimeSpan.FronSeconds(LeapSeconds);}}
    void Dispose()
    { //obviously this isn't needed}
}
```

So the question is, should I impose the `IDisposable` requirement when I expect most implementations will be using system resources that need to be released? Currently I do just that as it is then easier when the user of the IDateTimeProvider is releasing resources and

```
if(myDateTimeProvider is IDisposable) ((IDisposable)myDateTimeProvider).Dispose();
```

would not be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the question is, should I impose the IDisposable requirement when I expect most implementations will be using system resources that need to be released?

This is debatable, but there are examples in the framework that follow this guideline.  A good example is [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) - it implements `IDisposable` even though there are subclasses where this is not necessary.

I would use caution about requiring this of your users, however, unless you truly are fairly certain that nearly all implementations will require `IDisposable`, and not just a few of them.

Comment: Thanks Reed, can always count on a good response from you.  This answers perfectly.  At the present time I can only guess at one implementation that would need use system resources so I'll go with requiring it for now.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the reason for providing an interface is to allow programmers to treat various implementations of a concept as having the same set of behavior.  If you implement `IDisposable` only on the classes that happen to manage system resources, you force programmers to deal with that implementation detail, adding complexity and fragility to your design.

If there's a chance that unmanaged resources might be referenced by your application when an object's usefulness expires, you should absolutely implement the `IDisposable` interface so that consumers of your class can use the Dispose Pattern to release those resources in a predictable manner.

As a reminder about the reason for the Dispose Pattern:

> In computer programming, the dispose pattern is a design pattern which is used to handle resource cleanup in runtime environments that use automatic garbage collection. The fundamental problem that the dispose pattern aims to solve is that, because objects in a garbage-collected environment have finalizers rather than destructors, there is no guarantee that an object will be destroyed at any deterministic point in time. The dispose pattern works around this by giving an object a method (usually called Dispose or similar) which frees any resources the object is holding onto.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispose_pattern

Comment: I don't think this really addresses the question.  I think the question is more "should IDisposable be required on my interface, or just the classes that need it?"

Comment: Indeed I do try to limit to only needed interfaces.  Fortunately the complexity of implementing the Dispose() pattern for those object that don't need it is quite simple so I would in this case assume there shouldn't be an issue with it.

Answer (score 1):

The $50,000 question is whether code will ever acquire *ownership* of objects which implement the interface without knowing their specific type and whether they require cleanup.  In situations where that could occur [by fast the most common examples being `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` and `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()`, though many other examples exist], client code must use one of two patterns:

- If the interface type does not implement `IDisposable` [as is the case with the non-generic `IEnumerator` returned by non-generic `IEnumerable`], then properly-written client code that has acquired ownership of the object must--before abandoning it--check whether the particular object implementing the interface also happens to implement `IDisposable` and, if so, call its `IDisposable.Dispose` implementation.
- If the interface does implement `IDisposable`, a properly-written client that has acquired ownership must--before abandoning the object--call `IDisposable.Dispose` on the object unless it somehow knows that the object doesn't actually need cleanup.  Note that even if an object doesn't do anything in its `IDisposable.Dispose` method, it will in many cases be faster to call it unconditionally than to spend any significant time determining whether the call is necessary.  Even if only 0.001% of the object instances would need cleanup, including `IDisposable` wouldn't impart any new obligations to the client code.  Rather, it would increase the likelihood that client code would fulfill its obligations, and reduce the cost of doing so for all objects--including the 99.999% of instances don't require cleanup.

If an interface is unlikely to ever be returned by factory methods nor used in any other scenario where the owner of an object wouldn't know whether cleanup is required, there's no need for the interface to implement `IDisposable`.  But for cases where the interface type may be returned by factory methods, it should implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: I think I agree.  This is why I decided to implement impose IDisposable on the interface.  I think complexity wise in the end, there will be less potential issues as an implementer that doesn't need it can simply implement an empty function and still nothing important is really lost.  Thanks for the response it was quite interesting.

Comment: @galford13x: Calling an empty `Dispose` function is so cheap that in most cases it's faster to do the call than check whether it's necessary.  There's only one case I know of where a means of checking whether an object needs `Dispose` could generally be a major win: when dealing with shared immutable objects in cases where it's unclear who the last user will be.  In such a case, figuring out when to call `Dispose` may require adding significant overhead to any consumer that *might* end up being the last one.  That's a pretty rare situation, though.